# Подскажите правильную короткую запись свойств подключенного шрифта?

Tags: css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i');
```

Подключил шрифт. Как правильно прописать короткой записью то что этот шрифт
размером `28px`, `Open Sans Regular`?

Answer (score 4):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i');

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 28px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor.</h1>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime, laborum.
  </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i');

body {
  font: 400 28px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

А если за странице больше 1 параграфа или заголовка, то лучше использовать `mixin`
К примеру, создали `mixin`

```
@mixin text($f-size, $f-family, $f-color) {
  font-size: $f-size;
  font-family: $f-family;
  color: $f-color;
}
```

Вызвали и передали нужные для конкретного элемента стили

```
@include text(10px, Open Sans, #000);
```